# python-pptx: control text outline color and width

Tags: python-pptx

In python-pptx, is it possible to set/change the text's outline color and width?

Manually you would select the textbox or highlight the text and select "Text Options" then select "Solid line" and then you can choose your color and change the width. See image below where I have changed the outline color to red and width to 3pt.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to like this answer: It's in the category of "examine the XML and confect it directly".